# Shifting keyboard position

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a edittext on main screen and I have a sliding drawer which I can slide in slide out on button click. The numeric keybad that we have in android. Can I shift the position of keyboard to that sliding panel? Is there any scope?

Need a suggestion or shall i make a custom keyboard for that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you please post a wire frame of your idea ?????

Comment: definetly. but I dont have 10 points so that i can post images.

Answer (score 0):

Hide keyboard when you open sliding drawer and show again when you close it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dima. But I am asking can we shift that keyboard on sliding panel instead of showing in bottom of the tab?